# Set selected value for DropDownListFor in controller does not work in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have this in my controller:

```
[Route("Checkout")]
public ActionResult Checkout()
{
    var sb = new ShoppingBagViewModel();
    sb.DestinationCountry = "Netherlands"; // I hoped that this was sufficient
    sb.CountriesSl.Single(c => c.Text.Equals("Netherlands", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Selected = true;
    return View(sb);
}
```

Quick watch in Visual Studio confirmed that the CountriesSl (which is of type `List<SelectListItem>`) has a selected value. (netherlands)

This is my razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DestinationCountry, Model.CountriesSl)
```

`DestinationCountry` is also a string prop in my viewmodel.
I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but I have looked at a lot of them and I just do not see it.
I also tried:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DestinationCountry, Model.CountriesSl)
```

Please do not just give me the answer, but also explain what my mistake is.

**edit** to make clear what the problem is: I get a nice option list in my razor view, but there is no item "selected" just the first one. When I look at the generated html, there is no selected item too.

**edit for Ric**

```
public List<SelectListItem> CountriesSl
{
    get
    {
        List<SelectListItem> _countries = HttpContext.Current.Cache["slCountries"] as List<SelectListItem>;
        if (_countries == null)
        {
            _countries = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (string s in System.IO.File.ReadLines(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/tmpwrite/countries.csv")))
            {
                var tmp = s.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                _countries.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = tmp[1], Value = tmp[0], Selected = false });
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("slCountries", _countries.OrderBy(c => c.Text).ToList(), null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        return _countries;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate your `List<SelectListItem>`? Do you set the `value` property as well as the `text`?

Comment: Strange, that the question and both answers have -1 score now and there is no motivation why everything is down voted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`DropDownListFor` tries to automatically match the value of the receiving property in the provided enumeration. I also had problems with this in the beginning.

Instead provide any list of entities in the viewmodel. I usually use something like `IDictionary<int, string>`. Then create the dropdown like this:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.DestinationCountry, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Key", "Value"))
```

Then the SelectList will automagically set the correct option where its Key matches DestinationCoutry.

Comment: So perhaps the thing is that I use the text value to set it to selected instead of the value. Perhaps this is all fixed when I fill `DestinationCountry` with the value of the dropdown instead of the text prop of the selecteditem.

Comment: You need to be using the value as you mentioned, just wanted to see you code and check that the value == text in which case it would work.

Comment: Lol I based it on the text value and tried to match that in the code behind. But razor ignores that and only works with the value. I will mark this as the answer, as this pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: OP already has a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Creating a `Dictionary` and then creating `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from it is just crazy. And this answer does not address the question at all.